# onkeydown как понять какая кнопка нажато

Tags: javascript

функция вместо того чтобы работать при нажатии на `ShiftLeft` работает при любых нажатиях

```js
document.onkeydown = function(event){
    let code = event.code
    if(event.code = 'ShiftLeft'){
        alert("Yes!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    document.onkeydown = function(event){
        let code = event.code
        if(event.code == 'ShiftLeft'){
            alert("Yes!")
        }
    }
```

вы пытались присвоить event.code значение 'ShiftLeft', а не сравнить их (мой пример работает верно)

Comment: Опа, косячек. спасибка